# I want to get firestore data in dequeueReusableCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I rewrote all the text and now I got the code I wanted to realize.
It can not be displayed on the tableCell, and the layout also collapses. I am sorry that the code and the body I wrote are not explained enough.

guard let userID = Auth.auth (). currentUser? .uid I want to always acquire userID with else {return}.

// guard let docSnapshot = querySnapshot, document.exists else {return}

Since an error occurs, it is commented out.

## Within viewidLoad of UIViewController

var profDict: [ProfDic] = [] is in the UIViewController.

profUIView is being added to UIViewController.

```
    func getFirebaseData() {

         db = Firestore.firestore()

        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}


        let ref = db.collection("users").document(userID)

        ref.getDocument{ (document, error) in

            if let document = document {
//                guard let docSnapshot = querySnapshot, document.exists else {return}
                if let prof = ProfDic(dictionary: document.data()!) {

                    self.profDict.append(prof)

                    print("Document data \(document.data())")
                }
            }else{
                print("Document does not exist")
            }

            self.profUIView.tableView1.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

## tableView1 has been added to ProfUIView.

```
class ProfUIView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        //omission...

            override init(frame: CGRect) {
                super.init(frame: frame)

                backgroundColor = .blue

                addSubview(tableView1)
                tableView1.anchor(top:  //omission...

                 sections = [
                    Section(type: .prof_Sec, items: [.prof]),
                    Section(type: .link_Sec, items: [.link]),
                    Section(type: .hoge_Sec, items: [.hoge0])
                ]

                tableView1.register(TableCell0.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TableCellId0)                  
                tableView1.register(TableCell3.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TableCellId3)                    
                tableView1.register(TableCell5.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TableCellId5)    



                tableView1.delegate = self
                tableView1.dataSource = self

             }

             var tableView1:UITableView = {
                 let table = UITableView()
                 table.backgroundColor = .gray
                 return table
             }()

             //omission                

             func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                  return sections.count
             }

             func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                  return (baseVC?.profDict.count)!//sections[section].items.count
             }                        

             func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {                            
                switch sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row] {                                
                   case .prof:
                       let cell0 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableCellId0, for: indexPath) as? TableCell0                                
                       cell0?.nameLabel.text = baseVC?.profDict[indexPath.row].userName 
                       return cell0!
               }

              //omission...   
            }   
        }
```

## Additional notes

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

struct ProfDic {

    var userName :String

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return
            ["userName" : userName

        ]
    }

}


extension ProfDic {

    init?(dictionary:[String:Any]) {

        guard let userName = dictionary["userName"] as? String
        else {return nil}

        self.init(userName: userName as String)

    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5VRB.png)

Comment: What’s this line doing: collection("users").document()

Comment: Firebase is async. You are returning the cell before the data has been downloaded from the database. Use a dispatch call to return the cell only after data is downloaded.

Comment: In cellForRow you should already have the data you will set in a cell even and before that you should know how many cells you want to show. I guess the standard solution is to load first page of items and load more when user approach the end of the list. TL;DR You need to load data before, store it in i.e. array in memory and just display in the table view.

Comment: Hello Galo.Thanks for your comment.

Where should I use DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData ()}? I am investigating, but I do not understand.

Comment: Hello Kamil. Thanks for your comment. What you are saying is that there are multiple users, how to display that list? What I want to ask is how to display on the profile screen for one user. If we can display userName for one person on one cell, we solve this question.

Comment: I tried writing in viewwillappear etc, but it can not be displayed. Where should I write DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData ()}?

Comment: I can not pass a value.

Comment: I would like to obtain from the firestore with a new body syntax. Please cooperate.

Comment: I have not been able to solve this problem for many months. Please let me know the missing parts to get in the body's syntax.

Comment: If you uploaded the project to github, I think that you can check it. Thank you.

Comment: I've been looking at it for several months, but I do not know. Is there anyone who can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an empty array of `ProfDic` elements:

`var profDict: [ProfDic] = []`

Then create a function to load your Firebase Data:

```
func getFirebaseData() {

    db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userRef = db.collection("users").getDocuments() {
        [weak self] (querySnapshot, error) in
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else {return}

            if let prof = ProfDic(dictionary: docSnapshot.data()!) {
                profDict.append(prof)
            }
        }
    tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Call this function `in viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`.

Then in `tableView` `cellForRowAt` you access your data like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row] {
    case .prof:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableCellId, for: indexPath) as? TableCell
        cell?.nameLabel.text = profDict[indexPath.row].userName
        return cell!
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Also in `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return profDict.count
}
```

Comment: guard let userID = Auth.auth (). currentUser? .uid else {return} has been added and edited the body. In this case, I would like to know how to obtain with addsnapshot lister.

Comment: I am sorry to change the text.

Comment: To remove index out of range in `tableView``numberOfRows` return `profDict.count`. Follow my logic and everything will work ok

Comment: I appreciate that you are showing code that can accomplish what I want to do. It should be correct, but it seems that there is an error due to my lack of description.

Comment: So I rewrote all the text. The rewritten text is the code that I actually devised writing. I would like you to tell me how to get from this code. I am trial and error as well.

Comment: I would like to obtain from the firestore with a new body syntax. Please cooperate.

Comment: You changed everything there. About layout collapsing, you have problems with constraints. Are you sure no data is received from Firebase?

Comment: Please tell me which parts of the layout are incomplete.

Comment: Have you tried reading the error here: `ref.getDocument{ (document, error) in` ?

Comment: Thankyou.I overlooked it. } Has been corrected and erased, but it can not be acquired before.

Comment: I have not been able to solve this problem for many months. Please let me know the missing parts to get in the body's syntax.

Comment: Can you share your project somewhere? Because there's a lot of missing info.

Comment: I'm sorry. There was a missing file in the uploaded project, so I added it to the text. I want you to see it.

Comment: If you uploaded the project to github, I think that you can check it. Thank you.

Comment: I've been looking at it for several months, but I do not know. Is there anyone who can solve it?

Comment: Can you share your firestore structure?

Comment: Thank you. Is it OK with the image added to the body?

Comment: It's not enough, because I cannot see if it's a collection or document, but try replacing: `let ref = db.collection("users").document(userID)` with `let ref = db.collection("users").collection(userID)`

Comment: Do I have to create a subcollection named userID?
db.collection ("users"). document (). collection (userID!). document ()

Comment: users is a collection. userID (random) is document. userName is the data. In this case, do you replace it as you say?

Comment: No, are you sure that you are using the right userid?

Comment: Yes.

let userID = Auth.auth (). currentUser? .uid

Login with FBSDK and its authentication.

Comment: Try using my code for retrieving data and tell me if it works, and then We can try to find your problem

Comment: Its on my answer

Comment: I understand. Although I have not made a sub collection now, I will try to make a new sub collection and get it. Many times Thank you.

Comment: I could not do it. After logging in FBSDK, I check whether data exists with addSnapshot, but I can not get data in subcolloecton even though it exists in firestore.

Comment: I want to take a method to check existence with addsnapshot and get userName with getdocument if it exists, but I can not do it. So, if you like, would you please provide me with a project that I can successfully edit by editing the project uploaded to github? It will not take a long time to correct the place where the project is incomplete.

Comment: It will be encouraging to reply many times, but if you can not solve this, the question is meaningless.
I tried as much as I could. It can not be acquired with subcollection.
Sorry, did you edit my github project and will you provide me with your project? Please do.

Comment: I will try on how to tell.I'm sorry but because I changed what I was seeing as a result of the process, I made a new question. Therefore, I close this question. Everyone who commented, Thank you very much. I will answer what I was asked to solve with the new question of the link. I am indebted to you. I'd appreciate it if you could share it if it is okay.